# Set value of an input box from part of url

Tags: url, input

ok so i have this address for a part of my website,

> localhost:2001/?botid=Alice&template=alice

and i want to make it so what i put after that will be put into the input box on the page. So something like this,

> localhost:2001/?botid=Alice&template=alice#Hello
>   how are you?

can anyone help out with a javascript or something?

heres the source code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--This is a simple example of an HTML chat template for Program D.-->
    <head>
        <!--The value associated with a bot predicate, such as
            "name", is inserted wherever you use a bot element
            with a name attribute that corresponds to a predicate name.-->
        <title>
            Dialogue with <bot name="name"/>
        </title>
        <!--This is a simple stylesheet to format the page.-->
        <style type="text/css">
            html
            {
            overflow: hidden;
            }
            p
            {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                text-align: left;
                background: transparent;
            }
            .fieldlabel
            {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #0000aa;
            }
            #userinput
            {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #aa0000;
            }
            .botresponse
            {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #00aa00;
            }
            .bottomtext
            {
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: italic;
                font-size: 10px;
            }
            li p
            {
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 0px;
            }
            ul
            {
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-right: 0px;
            }
            form
            {
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 0px;
            }
            #audio
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function playPause() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
  if (myVideo.paused)
    myVideo.play();
  else
    myVideo.play();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('text')[0].value = window.location.hash.substring(1);
</script>
    </head>
    <!--The body element is set to automatically give focus to the
        input field each time the document is loaded.-->
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" width="500">
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" valign="top">
                    <p class="fieldlabel">
                        You said:
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="70%" valign="top">
                    <p id="userinput">
                        <userinput/>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" valign="top">
                    <p class="fieldlabel">
                        <!--The name of the bot will be substituted here.-->
                        <bot name="name"/> said:
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td width="70%" valign="top">
                    <p class="botresponse">
                        <!--The bot's response will be substituted here.-->
                        <reply></reply><response/>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" colspan="2" valign="top">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="text" size="50" name="text" id="text" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 190) document.getElementById('go').click()" x-webkit-speech />
                        <input type="submit" id="go" value="Say" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100%" colspan="2" valign="top">
                    <p class="bottomtext">
                        <!--Again we display the bot name, and also the hostname.-->
                        You are speaking with <bot name="name"/> from <hostname/>.
                    </p>
                    <p class="bottomtext">
                        <!--Here is an example of getting another bot predicate value (master).-->
                        <bot name="name"/>'s botmaster is <bot name="master"/>.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        You can:
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>
                                <!--This link will request a login form.-->
                                <a href="?login=yes">log in</a>.
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>
                                <!--This link will request a new user registration form.-->
                                <a href="?register=yes">register a new username and password</a>.
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<audio id="audio" onended="document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=><response/>" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('input').val(window.location.hash.substring(1));
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

Either way, you have to make sure the DOM is loaded.  If you want to unescape it, use [`decodeURIComponent`](http://decodeURIComponent)  E.g.:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substring(1));
}, false);
```

Comment: do i need to like the jquary js to my site to make this work?

Comment: @Trevor, no, you can do it without libraries.

Comment: does the focus need to be on the text box?

Comment: Nope, doesn't matter.  However, you do have to make sure the page is loaded.

Comment: this is the error safari gives me, `'document.getElementById('text')' [null] is not an object.`

Comment: @Trevor, post your full HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: @Matthew when there is a space in the url the outcome has %20 in the input box

Comment: you are very javascript savvy

Comment: then how can i make the form auto submit if the hash was used for text input?

Comment: @Trevor, you may want to ask that as a separate question.  But basically, if there is a hash (check `.length`), fill the input (what you have already) and call the submit method of the form.  You can also make the input hidden.

Comment: @Matthew, Thanks for the help, I looked up JavaScript on hash change and a got a person who had posted a question with 20k views and still no checked answer lol

Answer (score 0):

window.location = window.location + '#' + document.getElementById('inputbox').text;